# Blackjack Java using MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, blackjack

I am creating a BlackJack game in Java and attempting to use the MVC design when creating it. I have so far created the following classes:
- Card: To hold create a card
- Deck: To create a deck filled with all 52 cards
- Hand: To hold a 'Hand' of Cards
- Player: To create a Player for game use
- BlackJackTest: Here I am testing all the functions of the game trying to get something working!

I have currently got to the point where I can show all 52 cards, and also deal 2 cards to a Hand and show this Hand. But I'm having a lot of trouble with the next steps. Ideally within the "BlackJackTest" class I would want to use this as a Game Engine where I would enter X amount of players and their names, and it would create the players, and loop through the system to play the game.

My problem is that I am completely stuck on what I should be doing next, or if I have done something wrong. My next task should be to implement a feature so that I can put up to 3 human players against a dealer, but am unsure of how to do this....and I should also implement hit/stand features which I'm not sure where or how I should be coding these.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJackTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*System.out.println(deck.getCard(0).toString());
        System.out.println(deck.getCard(0).getSuit());
        System.out.println(deck.getCard(0).getSuitCode());
        System.out.println(deck.getCard(0).getValue());
        System.out.println(deck.getCard(0).getValueCode());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(deck.cardsLeft());
        hand.addCard( deck.dealCard() );
        hand.addCard( deck.dealCard() );
        hand.showHand();
        System.out.println(deck.cardsLeft());
        System.out.println(hand.getHandSize());
        System.out.println(hand.getCard(0));
        System.out.println(hand.getCard(1));
        System.out.println(hand.getBlackJackValue());
        System.out.println();
        */

        Deck deck = new Deck();

        Hand p1hand = new Hand();
        Player player = new Player();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        player.setName(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Welcome " + player.getName() + "!");

        player.setHand(p1hand);

        p1hand.addCard( deck.dealCard() );
        p1hand.addCard( deck.dealCard() );

        System.out.println(player.getName() + ": ");
        p1hand.showHand();
        System.out.println("Score: " + p1hand.getBlackJackValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Card {

    public enum Value {
        TWO(2),
        THREE(3),
        FOUR(4),
        FIVE(5),
        SIX(6),
        SEVEN(7),
        EIGHT(8),
        NINE(9),
        TEN(10),
        JACK(10),
        QUEEN(10),
        KING(10),
        ACE(1);

        public final int value;

        Value(int c) {
            value = c;
        }
    }

    public enum Suit {
        CLUBS('C'),
        SPADES('S'),
        DIAMONDS('D'),
        HEARTS('H');

        public final char symbol;

        Suit(char c) {
            symbol = c;
        }
    }

    private Suit suit;
    private Value value;

    public Card(Suit suit, Value value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public char getSuitCode() {
        return suit.symbol;
    }

    public int getValueCode() {
        return value.value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck {

    private List<Card> deck = new LinkedList<Card>();

    public Deck() {
        for(Card.Suit suit : Card.Suit.values()) {
            for(Card.Value value : Card.Value.values()) {
                deck.add(new Card(suit,value));
            }
        }
        shuffle();
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    public int cardsLeft() {
          // As cards are dealt from the deck, the number of cards left
          // decreases.  This function returns the number of cards that
          // are still left in the deck.
        return deck.size();
    }

    public Card dealCard() {
          // Deals one card from the deck and returns it.
        if (deck.size() == 52) {
           shuffle();
        }
        Card temp;
        temp = deck.get(0);
        remove(0);
        return temp;
    }

    public Card getCard(int i) {
        return deck.get(i);
    }

    public Card remove(int i) {
        Card c = deck.get(i);
        deck.remove(i);
        return c;
    }   

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Hand {
    private Vector<Card> hand;

    public Hand() {
      hand = new Vector<Card>();
    }

    public void addCard(Card c) {
        if (c != null)
            hand.addElement(c);
    }

    public void showHand() {
        for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(hand.elementAt(i));
        }
    }

    public int getHandSize() {
        return hand.size();
    }

    public Card getCard(int position) {
        if(position >= 0 && position < hand.size())
            return (Card)hand.elementAt(position);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public int getBlackJackValue() {
        int val = 0;
        boolean ace = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            Card card;
            card = getCard(i);
            val += card.getValueCode();

            if(card.getValueCode() == 1) {
                ace = true;
            }
        }

        if(ace == true && val + 10 <= 21) {
            val += 10;
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private Hand hand;

    public Player() {
        this.hand = null;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setHand(Hand h) {
        this.hand = h;
    }

    public void getHand(){
        hand.showHand();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds as if a Bank-class (Dealer) would be useful, who would share much methods with Human Player - both would be Players. Maybe a third kind of Player, a Robot, which acts according to a ruleset would be possible then.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start on your model classes, I'd start working on the View and Controller parts of the project.  While you could certainly modify main() to incorporate multiple players (just instantiate multiple player objects, store them in a list, and deal cards round-robin), you'll have to discard a lot of it if/when you decide to move to a non-console view and controller.

Your controller design will have a lot to do with how you receive and respond to user input (i.e. hit/stand).  It's job is to relay input from from the view (currently via console.in) to the model.  So your view would display a prompt asking the user what they want to do, read in their response, and notify the controller.  The controller would map this input to the appropriate objects/methods in your model classes.

Hope that's helpful!

Steve

Comment: LOL, just saw that was from last year.  Oh well, I'll let the answer stand in case anyone else stumbles upon this.